# Is javax.validation.ConstraintPayload deprecated in hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I have downloaded the latest [Bean-Validation API](http://hibernate.org/validator/downloads/).

Is ***javax.validation.ConstraintPayload*** deprecated in the latest release. What do i use instead?

The snippet which used to work appears in red now,

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = EmailConstraintValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Email {
    String message() default "{validator.email}";

    Class<? extends ConstraintPayload>[] payload() default {};

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you worked with a very old preview version of the Bean Validation API before. It is `javax.validation.Payload` as of Bean Validation 1.0.